# Load data in object of Generic class C#

Tags: c#, class, object, generics

I want to have an instance of a generic class and get data loaded in that instance. The sample code is given as under:

```
public class AuthorCollector : EvoObjectCollector<Author>
{
   static ConnectionClass _cs = new ConnectionClass();
   SqlConnection _con;
   public AuthorCollector()
   {
      _con = _cs.GetConnection();
   }

   public override List<Author> CollectAuthors(int _startYear, int _endYear)
   {  
      List<Author> _eAthors = new List<Author>();
      // ... method implementation...  
      // ... using SqlDataReader
      return _eAuthors;  
   }  
}
```

and in the main class

```
public class Test  
{
   public static void Main(String[] _args)
   {
      int _ITERATIONS = 100;
      // EvoNetwork main class
      EvoNetwork<Author> _mEvoNetwork = new EvoNetwork<Author>(/*constructor properties*/);

      // Create a collector which collects Author from DB. 
      EvoObjectCollector<Author> _mCollector = new AuthorCollector();  

      // Create a converter which converts Author into EvoObject.
      EvoObjectConverter<Author> _mConverter = new AuthorPCVConverter();  

      var _result = _mEvoNetwork.Build(_mCollector, _mConverter, _ITERATIONS);

      // ... rest of the implementation...  
   }
}
```

I want to have data in `_mCollector` i.e. object of `EvoObjectCollector<Author>` is created.
Should I put `CollectAuthors()` method of class `AuthorCollector()` inside constructor to get data as object of class is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you should not use a overrideable method in the constructor. instead use constructor injection or call a `initialize` method afterwards. This could be abstracted by using a `factory` which calls the `initialize` method and returns the initialized object.

Another possiblity would also be to use the `_startYear` and the `_endYear` as input parameters for the constructor and call a private method which initializes the object.

You could change your design like followed:

```
public abstract class EvoObjectCollector<T> { 

    protected List<T> collection; 

    // Instead of the startYear and the endYear a CollectionContext could be added
    public abstract void Collect(int startYear, int endYear); 

    public List<T> GetCurrentCollection() { 
        return collection; 
    } 
} 

public AuthorCollector : EvoObjectCollector<Author> { 

    public AuthorCollector(int startYear, int endYear) { 
        Collect(startYear, endYear); 
    } 

    public void Collect(int startYear, int endYear) { 
        // Collect the collection 
        collection = ... 
    } 
}
```

Comment: If I provide `_startYear` and `_endYear` as input parameters to constructor, then private method calling i.e. `CollectAuthor()` will be inside same constructor?

Comment: Yes when it is a `private` method, so that no one can change the logic of the method.

Comment: You mean I should define constructors as:  
`public AuthorCollector()
{
    _con = _cs.GetConnection();
}

public AuthorCollector(int _startYear, int _endYear)
{
   CollectAuthors(_startYear, _endYear);
}`

Comment: But CollectAuthors() will return a `List<Author>`, how to handle this?

Comment: The class `AuthorCollector` has no properties to initialize other than an overrideable method

Comment: Does the `CollectAuthors` method initialze properties in the object which you have not mentioned in the code above?

Comment: I want to declare an object of class `AuthorCollector` and at the same time the method `CollectAuthors()` should work and give me the data from database into that object. Is it possible as object is of type `EvoObjectCollector<Author>` and author list will be of type `List<Author>`?

Comment: `CollectAuthors` method only accepts two parameters i.e. `_startYear` and `_endYear` and returns a list of authors of type `List<Author>`

Comment: Do you need to store the data from the `CollectAuthors` at the beginning?

Comment: I want to store the data as I declared the object as in class `Test` i.e. `_mCollector`

Comment: Have you checked the answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114189/discussion-between-taufel-and-kevin-wallis).

Comment: I haven't checked yet